# Rails: Serializing objects in a database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, serialization, model, object

I'm looking for some general guidance on serializing objects in a database.

1. What are serialized objects?
2. What are some best-practice scenarios for serializing objects in a DB?
3. What attributes do you use when creating the column in the DB so you can use a serialized object?
4. How to save a serialized object?
5. And how to access the serialized object and its attributes? (Using hashes?)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

> In computer science, in the context of data storage and transmission, serialization is the process of converting a data structure or object into a sequence of bits so that it can be stored in a file, a memory buffer, or transmitted across a network connection link to be "resurrected" later in the same or another computer environment.
>   (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization)

1. So serialized objects (in the context of ActiveRecord) are text/string representations of objects (encoded using YAML). When serialized, you can save (almost) any Ruby object in a single database field.
2. You can use serialization if you have somewhat complex objects that you need to save in a database and you don't need to retrieve records based on the contents of a serialized attribute. I used them for example for storing preferences for users of a webapp: the preferences were basically hashes that I wanted to save in a single db field.

3./4./5. Use [ActiveRecord::Base.serialize](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M001799) as Marc-André Lafortune suggested:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :preferences
end

u = User.new
u.preferences = {:show_tooltips => true, :use_extended_menu => false, ...}
u.save

# ...

u = User.find(23)
u.preferences # => {:show_tooltips => true, :use_extended_menu => false, ...}
```

Answer (score 8):

Really easy. Check the [doc](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods/serialize) for [`ActiveRecord::Base.serialize`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods/serialize).

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [MessagePack](http://msgpack.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Rails 4 with Postgresql, Rails 4 supports hstore field which can store hashes and allows queries too.
http://blog.remarkablelabs.com/2012/12/a-love-affair-with-postgresql-rails-4-countdown-to-2013