# ActiveRecord tables with many columns: is there a better way?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, database-design

I would like to know whether I am appropriately using table attributes to describe objects or whether there is a more efficient and advisable approach for certain types of attributes.

I have two ActiveRecord tables, `foods` and `lists`. Both tables have many columns because each object has many attributes (calories, fat, protein, etc.).

In addition to these intrinsic characteristics, I find myself adding columns to the table for attributes that represent an object’s membership in a group or user-defined properties.

*Group membership data* indicate whether a food is a dessert or a meat, among other categories. For this, I have columns with binary or categorical (char) data.

*User-defined property data* include “maximum calories” or “maximum fat” attributes for a list. If I have a column for “maximum” corresponding to each “total” (e.g., “maximum calories” and “total calories”), this of course doubles the number of columns.

Dessert and meat are intrinsic properties in that they cannot be altered by the user, but it seems they could be more efficiently represented by an array of food ids or a hash. Having so many data points (and columns) to represent this simple categorization seems redundant, and my tables are so big. The reason I have not switched to arrays for group membership data is because I like how this data is currently accessible by the object itself. It’s intuitive, centralized, and seemingly less error-prone.

I don’t have an idea for how else I would manage user-defined “maximums” for lists, and maybe this proliferation of columns/attributes is the best option.

I would appreciate any advice or appraisal of my approach and suggestions of possible alternatives.

Comment: Which database system?  If you're using Postgres, you can store extended attributes in a column of type JSON.

Comment: I am using PostgreSQL. I will look into this. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you @Sean; I have made some progress. I now have a JSON column that contains the data. I am having trouble making it possible for the user to edit, though I can update the values using a Service Object that gets called in the create method. When I allow the user to edit the JSON value through a form_for, the user-entered value is not recognized (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass). The other clue is that when I include a presence: true validation, I receive a "cannot be blank" error even when there is a value. Do you have any suggestions for what to explore? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use serialize and store an text object in the database but when you selecting it will be accessed as an HASH or ARRAY again, this can solve the problem for you instead of duplicating fields store it as HASH and then read from it.

check out this:

[Rails: Serializing objects in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2959661/rails-serializing-objects-in-a-database)

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/serialize/class

Comment: Thank you. I have made use of this; also, I have gotten less hesitant about adding attributes to Models. When I asked the question, I was afraid of having "too many columns," but now I'm not sure why. I don't have _that_ many attributes, and whether it's best to store them as separate attributes versus serialized text object just depends on the situation.